# template function for complex types

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Is there any way in C++17 or older to use single template implementation of function `compute` in the code below?

```
template <typename T>
class C
{
    public:

        T x, y;

        C() = default;
        C(T x, T y) : x(x), y(y) {}

        operator T() const { return x; }
        C operator +(const C<T> &c) const { return C(x + c.x, y + c.y); }
        C operator +(const T &t) const { return C(x + t, y); }
};

template <typename T>
void compute(C<T> *a, T *b, size_t size)
{
    while (size--)
        a[size] = a[size] + b[size];
}

template <typename T>
void compute(T *a, C<T> *b, size_t size)
{
    while (size--)
        a[size] = a[size] + b[size];
}

template <typename T>
void compute(C<T> *a, C<T> *b, size_t size)
{
    while (size--)
        a[size] = a[size] + b[size];
}

int main()
{
    const size_t size = 4;
    C<float> a[size];
    float b[size];
    compute(a, b, size);
    compute(b, a, size);
    compute(a, a, size);
}
```

Comment: Can't you just add another type `U` in the template?

Comment: How exacting do you want to be?  Is it okay to a `C<float>[]` with a `double[]`?

Comment: There is, but it's not pretty. You can always have a common implementation that each function calls if your concern is repeating the body.

Comment: whats wrong with `temnplate <typename A,typename B> void compute(A* a,B* b,size_t size)` ?

Comment: The intention is that I need to force C to have exactly the same type in case of `*a` and `*b` parameters. Like `C <T> *a, T *b`. And yes, my concern is the repeating body,

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you are willing to tolerate a little boilerplate (I imagine you have many, many functions just like `compute`).

```
template <typename A, typename B>
struct is_cable_t : std::false_type {};

template <typename A>
struct is_cable_t<A, C<A>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename A>
struct is_cable_t<C<A>, A> : std::true_type {};

template <typename A>
struct is_cable_t<C<A>, C<A>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename A, typename B>
constexpr bool is_cable_v = is_cable_t<A,B>::value;

template <typename K, typename S, 
          typename R = typename std::enable_if<is_cable_v<K,S>>::type>
void compute(K *a, S *b, size_t size)
{
    while (size--)
        a[size] = a[size] + b[size];
}
```

Comment: It does the thing! Is there any way to simplify it? I would like to make it clear for other code readers :)